# Android Studio unable to run project: NoClassDefFoundError: com/intellij/notificataon/Notification

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, android-studio-2.1

I haven't found solution for this. Whenever I click run project, nothing happened. After several times hitting the run button, I realized there are plenty of "NoClassDefFoundError: com/intellij/notificataon/Notification" showed in the Event Log. Isn't it error because of the typo in "notificataon"?

I was just fixing some minor bug and I tried to run and this happen. before this everything run fine.
I tried to clean, rebuild, invalidate cache and restart android studio, same problem still presist. 
Is someone have idea what's going on? How to fix the "notificataon" part ?

[image]

EDIT:
it's fixed for now but I still can't figure out how to fix this bug. **I ended up re-install Android Studio** and now it works again.

Comment: @Tim already did. not working

Comment: Are you using preview version of Android Studio??

Comment: @sJy nope, I am using Android Studio 2.1.

Comment: this could have happened if your `app.iml` is corrupt. I've experienced something like this once. remove your `app.iml `and let android studio create the new one.

Comment: @isnotmenow I tried as you said.. but now I still can't run because there's no module in the configuration. How to fix it?

Comment: close then reopen your project.

Comment: @isnotmenow Successfully created new app.iml file but still unable to run the project..

Comment: is still the same error?

Comment: @isnotmenow yes, the "notificataon" still appears. I wonder where's this typo file located..

Comment: Please disable the Instant Run option from the Settings. It creates the issue with File Typo mistake.

Answer (score 0):

There is a 'ghost' bug with Android Studio and people have reported that the problem can be fixed with one (or more of the following) :

1) There is a **conflict between the project's android support library version and the version in its library projects.**
Set the same version to the android support library in the project and in the library projects that are included and then run build clean.

2) **Clean Android Studio's cache** by doing `File->Invalidate Caches/Restart`

3) **Look for broken inclusions** (such as .jar files that have changed and/or been removed) and solve them (add new/incorrupt versions)